# Difficulty Reading Text from Excel file

Tags: excel, text, xlrd

I'm working on a project where I am trying to search large amounts of text from an excel file for keywords. These keywords are citations in their various formats, (e.g. XXXXXX, YYYY), and then also to search the text for citations which contain the last name of the author. In excel, the C column is the authors last names, and the D column is the text of the writing. I am working with xlrd, but I do not know how to use the items from list "L" search the items in list "L1". Ultimately, I need to search list "L1" (the text) for citations, and then search L1 again for citations which have the same name as the corresponding cell in L, (e.g. C3 = Smith, must search D3 for any citation which has the name Smith). Any help with this, or other tips/methods for my task would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my current code for searching the excel file.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname

book = open_workbook("C:\Python27\Doc\Book3.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for year in xrange(1900,2014):
    citation = str(year) or str(year) + ')' or '(' + str(year) + ')' or str(year) + ';'

firstc = sheet.col_values(2)
secondc = sheet.col_values(3)
L = [firstc]
L1 = [secondc]
if citation in L1:
    print 'citation ' + str(year)
if L in L1:
     print 'self-cite ' + str(year)
for item in L1:
    if citation in item:
        print item
```

I am somewhat of a novice at python and I apologize for bothering you all, but I have had difficulty finding pre-written topics on searching text files. Thank you!

Best

Answer (score 0):

You can't look if L (which is a list) is in L1. You can look to see if the items in L are in L1. For example:

```
>>> s = 'abcde'
>>> b = ['a', 'f', 'g', 'b']
>>> b
['a', 'f', 'g', 'b']
>>> for i in b:
...    if i in s:
...     print i
...    else:
...     print "nope"
... 
a
nope
nope
b
>>>
```

If you have two lists, you'll need to loop over both, with a nested for loop:

```
for i in b:
  for j in L1:
    do stuff
```

Hope that gives you a start.

ETA:
You can use enumerate to get the index of the item you're looping on currently and use that to get into the right row in the second list:

```
>>> b = ['a', 'f', 'g', 'b']
>>> L1 = ['worda', 'words including b', 'many many words', 'a lot more words']

>>> for i, j in enumerate(b):
...   if j in L1[i]: 
...     print j
...   else:
...     print i, j
a
1 f
2 g
3 b
>>>
```

Combine that with row_values and you might have what you need.

Comment: I guess my problem is that I need to figure out how to automate the process of searching within a row...

Comment: I am not terribly familiar with xlrd, but I'd suggest seeing if row_values might help.    row_values(rowx, start_colx=0, end_colx=None) [#]
Returns a slice of the values of the cells in the given row.

Comment: See my updated answer above, which should give you the row index you'll need to use with row_values.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. your advice was very helpful but for some reason it doesn't seem to work when I try to use the columns from the excel spreadsheet. Additionally, row_value seems like a dead end. I'm wondering if there's a problem with excel importing the data as float and not as text... Who knows.